# How to extract only noun phrase from file using opennlp?

Tags: java, opennlp

(TOP (NP (NP (NN john) (NNS works)) (PP (IN in) (NP (NN Kollam) (NN Kerala)))))
I got the output as above.But I want noun phrase only.I  cant able to process the file.How can i implement it.

Comment: Do you have any criteria for noun ?
i.e NN representing Noun here ?

Comment: //Try this it will return all Nouns
 List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[(]NN (.*?)[)]")
     .matcher("(TOP (NP (NP (NN john) (NNS works)) (PP (IN in) (NP (NN Kollam) (NN Kerala)))))");
 while (m.find()) {
   allMatches.add(m.group());
 }
 for(int i=0;i<allMatches.size();i++){
     System.out.println(allMatches.get(i));
 }

Comment: Not noun want noun phrase file i am not able to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Parser? Why don't you use Chunker instead? Try:

```
$ echo "john works in Kollam Kerala." | opennlp TokenizerME en-token.bin | opennlp POSTagger en-pos.bin | opennlp ChunkerME en-chunker.bin
```

It displays:

```
 [NP john_NN works_NNS ] [PP in_IN ] [NP Kollam_NNP Kerala_NNP ] ._.
```

Comment: I am using chunker ..but i want also NP from file .A file which contain lot of noun phrases .SO who can it possible

Comment: I am using chunker ..but i want also NP from file .A file which contain lot of noun phrases .SO who can it possible